# Showing a set is a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $X$ denote the set of function $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $ and $X$ is a real linear space. Define $A$ and $B$ by:

$A = \{x \in  X \mid x(0) = 0\}$

$B = \{y \in X \mid y(1) = 0 \}$

Show $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of $X$.

---

To show that a set is a subspace, we have to show that the set is closed under multiplication and addition. However, i'm not really sure how we can do that with the information given. Advice?

Comment: For example: If $f,g$ are fucntion with $f(1)=g(1)=0$, what can you say about $f+g$?

Comment: Alternatively, note that e.g. $B$ is the kernel of the linear(!) map $X\to \mathbb R$, $f\mapsto f(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a set is a sub vector space, one must show that the set contains the element 0, is closed under addition, and closed under scalar multiplication.

Let's look at set $A$.

Does A contain the $0$ element?  The answer is yes because the zero function is one where $x(0)=0$.

Is it closed under scalar multiplication?  The answer is yes.  For any function $x\in X$, $(\alpha x)(0)=0$.  So $(\alpha x)\in X$.

Is it closed under vector addition?  The answer is yes.  Let $x_1,x_2\in X$.  $(x_1+x_2)(0)=0$, so $(x_1+x_2)\in X$.

End of proof.

Comment: As a note to the exercise it says that $A \cap B$ is also a subspace. How is that so? I can see how $A \cup B$ isn't because it isn't closed under multiplication.

Comment: You've just got to go through the same procedure of showing that the set $A\cap B$ is a subspace.  Specifically, you've got to show that $A\cap B$ contains the $0$ vector, is closed under scalar multiplication, and closed under addition.  Let's take scalar multiplication.  If I give you a vector $b\in A\cap B$ and multiply it by a scalar $\alpha$, is it in $A\cap B$?  $(\alpha b)(0)=\alpha \cdot b(0) = 0$, and $(\alpha b)(1)=\alpha \cdot b(1)=\alpha \cdot 0=0$.  So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\phi_k:X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi_k(f) = f(k)$. Note that $\phi_k$ is linear.

Then $A=\ker \phi_0, B= \ker \phi_1$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kernals yet. I suppose from your answer, it is sufficient to show that both $A$ and $B$ are kernals to show that they are subspaces?

Comment: Well, the kernel is automatically a subspace, which is why I did it this way. You could show directly that if $\phi_k(f) = 0$ then $\phi_k(\lambda f) = 0$ and if $\phi_k(f) = 0$, $\phi_k(g) = 0$ then $\phi_k(f+g) = 0$. This would show that the $f$ satisfying $\phi_k(f) = 0$ form a subspace.